Exact way of defining seed for random number generation in fortran
I am trying  to simulate a physical problem (Brownian dynamics) for which I need to generate random numbers.
Previously, I was just using the following to choose random numbers from a Gaussian distribution:
subroutine box_muller(l)
implicit none

real :: l, u1, u2
real, parameter :: pi = acos(-1.0)
 
 call random_seed()
 
 call random_number(u1)
 call random_number(u2)
 
 l = sqrt(-2*log(u1))*cos(2*pi*u2)
end subroutine

which is the Box-Muller algorithm.
I was calling this subroutine at each instant (time-step).
But I think I have not yet understood how to properly use the call random_seed() stuff.
For example, I was trying the following after some internet searches:
program seeding
implicit none

integer:: n
INTEGER :: seed 
REAL :: num

 CALL RANDOM_SEED (size=seed)
 seed = 123456789
DO n = 1, 5

 CALL RANDOM_NUMBER(num)

 PRINT *, num

END DO
    
end program

It gives the following output:
4.80166674E-02
  0.797537327    
  0.294925630    
  0.107502699    
  0.987043023 

Though I don't know if I have did it correctly.
I also tried the following in my main problem:
subroutine box_muller(x)

implicit none

integer :: n
integer,allocatable :: seed(:)

real,intent(out) :: x
real,parameter :: pi=3.14159265
real :: u1,u2
   
 call random_seed(size=n)
 allocate(seed(n))
 seed = 12    ! putting arbitrary seed to all elements

 call random_number(u1)
 call random_number(u2)
 x = sqrt(-2*log(u1))*cos(2*pi*u2)
end subroutine

But BELIEVE ME, I UNDERSTOOD NOTHING OF WHAT I AM DOING.
I just want to fix a particular seed for my problem, start generating random numbers, and concentrate on the other physical aspects!
The questions are -

How exactly to:
(a)  call random_seed(),
(b) defining the exact integral value of seed (like e.g. "123456789") for initialisation,
(c) putting call random_number(),
(d) what argument to put in random_seed(),
(e) SIZE, GET, PUT ... what to use?


You either care about random seeds fully or not at all. Even with gfortran there's no way to pretend to care about "an integral value of seed": different versions treat the seed differently. You need to set the seed appropriately for a specific generator.

Note your code is at least Fortran 2003, it's certainly not fortran95 compliant, so I've adjusted the title accordingly

Do you want/need the sequence of random numbers to be repeatable from run to run? If no, you don't have to call random_seed() at all. If yes, your last piece of code is almost correct, but it misses a call:
integer :: n
integer,allocatable :: seed(:)
   
call random_seed(size=n)   ! n is processor-dependent
allocate(seed(n))
seed = 12                  ! putting arbitrary seed to all elements
call random_seed(put=seed) ! effectively initializing the RNG with the seed


Not exactly repeatable but not too far apart, in different runs - that's what I guess. And maybe just that comment "n is processor-dependent" is what I needed!

@QuestionTheAnswer  This should be completely exactly repeatable - on this specific compiler version. Other compiler versions  may have, and other compiles do have, different generators. Old gfortran versions used a simpler generator of lower quality. Other compilers could also have something of lower quality. The generator used by current gfortran is very good, but you do not get all its features, like the jump function.

While @PierU's code and description is correct, there is another possible solution to your problem.  Instead of calling random_seed() and setting the prng into a known state, you can use call random_init(repeatable=.true., image_distinct=.false.).  The repeatable=.true. will seed the generator with the same set of seeds every time you execute the code.  Once you've debugged the code, you can set repeatable to .false. and a (usually) different set of seeds is used upon each execution.
